# What is the significance of the scene the proprietor is watching during the "laundry scene"?

Tags: analysis, ninja-assassin

In *Ninja Assassin*, the hero, played by Rain, is attacked in a laundromat by an assassin played by Linh Đan Phạm.

The scene is cut with shots of the proprietor of the laundromat watching what looks like a samurai movie.

**Which movie is it? And what is its significance?**

Comment: It looks more like a [korean movie/series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Korea-gat-01.jpg) than a samurai movie. It is probably used either to enforce the [stereotype](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-dry-cleaning-business-so-popular-among-Korean-Americans) of korean people owning laundromats, or to pay homage to the lead actor who is also korean.

Comment: The movie the laundry man is watching looks like Kanchee.